# Setting PYTHONPATH for running opencv

Tags: python, bash, opencv, segmentation-fault

I have installed opencv and run it by `import cv2`. I found that if I didn't run `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/opencv/lib`, it will have `segmentation error 11`. If I export it in the terminal and then run my python script, it will works perfectly. However, every time I restart the terminal, I need to export PYTHONPATH. So I added `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/opencv/lib` to `.bash_profile` and `source .bash_profile`. When I try `echo $PYTHONPATH`, it shows that the directory has been successfully added. However, when I run the program, it still have `segmentation error 11`, unless I run the export again in the bash shell. I also tried to edit `.bashrc` and no solve this problem. Why this happen?

Update==========

I know why this happened now, my `PYTHONPATH` also contain `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, and it conflicts with the cv path. If this path is put before the cv path, python will search this path first, which gives out the problem described here.

Comment: How do you run your python program? From the same bash shell?

Comment: @tobspr Yes of course

Comment: What does `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` say?

Comment: @tobspr Thanks, I solved the problem and updated the question above.